# Re-export as default in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript we can re-export modules in the following way:

```
export * from './validators'; // Re-export all exports
export { validate as stringValidator } from './validators/string'; // Re-export with changed name
```

My question is about whether it is possible to re-export as default, e.g. combine the following two statements into one:

```
import * as validators from './validators';
export default validators;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
export { default } from './validators';
```

Comment: If you have more than one of these, you will get a "duplicate identifier" error upon running "tsc". I'm using tsc v3.0.3.

Comment: @Obsidian you can assign them names like this
`export { default as validators } from './validators';`

Answer (score 2):

> combine the following two statements into one

No. You need two statements.